# How to make a that when a buıtton pressed a text change in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, uibutton

I wanna a text change acording to how many times a button clicked?

Any one with a solution??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Javascript that will change based on the number of times clicked.

An important thing to remember though - session storage will set your value to 0 when the tab is closed, local storage does not.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<p><span>You have clicked the button </span>
<span id="result"></span>
<span> time(s).</span></p>
```